# Justifying steps of a proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Given a Banach space X consider the space of linear operators $L(X,X)$, let $T\in L(X,X)$
> such that $||T-I||<1$ show $\sum(I-T)^n$ converge to $T^{-1}$.

So, since $X$ is Banach we know the space $L(X,X)$ is also Banach, [skipping the part where I showed the series $\sum(I-T)^n$ is convergent in $L(X,X)$ and setting the limit to be $T^{-1}$]
I am not sure if what I did in the following equalities are legal?

\begin{align}
        TT^{-1}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum^k_{n=0}T(I-T)^n&=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum^k_{n=0}(I-(I-T))(I-T)^n \nonumber \\
        &=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum^k_{n=0}(I-T)^n-(I-T)^{n+1} 
        \newline &=\lim_{k\to \infty}\sum^k_{n=0}(I-T)^n(I-(I-T)) 
        \newline &=T^{-1}T
    \end{align}

Comment: Your first step implicitly assumes that $T^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (I-T)^n$. Try looking at $\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(I-T)^n$ and see if you can spot a telescoping series.

Comment: @ColeG97 Hi, thanks for the comment. But I cant see a telescoping series. Do you mind pointing it out ? Thanks

Comment: In your post you already worked out a lot of the necessary steps... Try writing out the first few terms of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(I-T\right)^n - (I-T)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @ColeG9 ok I see it now, thank you! I was writing out a different expression before.